# Replacing li tag if it's opening and closing tag lies in between span opening and closing tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an input that consists of span opening and closing tag and in between if li opening and closing tags lie, I want to replace li tag with something. I have tried writing regex for it, you people can view it here:
https://regex101.com/r/vI1sY8/1 but it is replacing the li tag that lies outside the span tags as well.

Example my input:

```
  lol <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> <br /> <li> this </li>  
  </span> <br /> this is something <li"> This is new </li>
```

My output should be:

```
  lol <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> <br /> <li style="background-color:limegreen;"> this </li>  
  </span> <br /> this is something <li"> This is new </li>
```

Comment: `$('span li').css('background-color','limegreen');` or `$('span li').attr('style','background-color:limegreen;');`

Comment: How does JS helps him if he wants to change the html itself?

Comment: You should use a DOM parser for tasks like that, regular expressions are notoriously unreliable for parsing HTML. Also, note that a `<li>` tag inside a `<span>` is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: not sure it is true for all HTML versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex did the trick for me. Just swap second subgroup ($2) with whatever.
For example:

```
$html = 'lol <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> <br /> <li> this </li>  </span> <br /> this is something <li"> This is new </li>';
$html = preg_replace('/(<span.+>.+)(<li>)(.+<\/li>.+<\/span>)/', '$1 replacement $3', $html);
```

result:

```
lol <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> <br />  replacement  this </li>  </span> <br /> this is something <li"> This is new </li>
```

Change replacement to whatever you need.

Comment: `<` and `>` are not special characters, you don't need to escape them. If you want to escape a character a single backslash should suffice.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are right. Updated my answer.

Comment: Bonus: if you want to avoid to escape the slash, choose an other pattern delimiter like `~`.

Comment: Thanks, it is just a habit from JS regex to use backslashes

Comment: @RonDadon If I want to put an exception that there is no another span style="background-color:limegreen;"> in between the opening and closing span tag, can it happen?

Comment: Because right now what it is doing is: <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> <li> one </li> </span> <li> two </li> <span style="background-color:limegreen;"> lol nothing </span> It changes the second li too, so there should be an exception in between that another span should not lie in between. If it could happen, I tried && !preg_match('/(<span style="background-color:limegreen;".+>.+)(<span style="background-color:limegreen;">)(<\/span>)/', $html)==1, but it did not work